# Ant Build Open Source Buddi failed

Tags: svn, ant, sourceforge

I had a problem when I ant build the Buddi accounting open source software. Please do some help.

I did the following:
svn co https://buddi.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/buddi/trunk@1801

and then I go to the workspace and do the build step:
ant

But it gives me the compilation message:

```
compile:
  [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/LeoLi/Documents/UMD/Master Study/Fall 2012/CMSC737/Buddi-3.4.1.3.src/build/classes
  [javac] /Users/LeoLi/Documents/UMD/Master Study/Fall 2012/CMSC737/Buddi-3.4.1.3.src/build.xml:473: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
  [javac] Compiling 252 source files to /Users/LeoLi/Documents/UMD/Master Study/Fall 2012/CMSC737/Buddi-3.4.1.3.src/build/classes
  [javac] /Users/LeoLi/Documents/UMD/Master Study/Fall 2012/CMSC737/Buddi-3.4.1.3.src/src/org/homeunix/thecave/buddi/Const.java:23: ?Ҳ???????
  [javac] ???ţ? ?? AccountBalance
  [javac] λ?ã? ?????? org.homeunix.thecave.buddi.plugin.builtin.report
  [javac] import org.homeunix.thecave.buddi.plugin.builtin.report.AccountBalance;
  [javac]                                                        ^
  [javac] /Users/LeoLi/Documents/UMD/Master Study/Fall 2012/CMSC737/Buddi-3.4.1.3.src/src/org/homeunix/thecave/buddi/Const.java:213: ?Ҳ???????
  [javac] ???ţ? ?? AccountBalance
  [javac] λ?ã? ?? org.homeunix.thecave.buddi.Const
  [javac]       AccountBalance.class.getCanonicalName(),
  [javac]       ^
  [javac] 2 ????
```

Then I tried to find AccountBalance.java inside the report directory, and no surprising, there is no such file there.

Maybe we need to do something before ant build the Buddi project?

Update: Have downloaded the version 1800, but has the compile time error as follows when built it:

```
[javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Buddi/workspace/build.xml:473: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 252 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Buddi/workspace/build/classes
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
[javac] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Buddi/workspace/src/org/homeunix/thecave/buddi/view/dialogs/ScheduledTransactionEditorDialog.java:136: error: getType() in ScheduledTransactionEditorDialog cannot override getType() in Window
[javac]     public String getType(){
[javac]                   ^
[javac]   return type String is not compatible with Type
[javac] Note: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Buddi/workspace/src/org/homeunix/thecave/buddi/plugin/builtin/preference/PluginPreferences.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 1 error
[javac] 1 warning
```

Seems like a deprecated API stuff. Previously, this method is protected, and I have changed it to be public. Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: What's the output of `javac -version`? I was successful with `javac 1.6.0_24` downloaded from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6u35-downloads-1836443.html) - Linux 32-bit version. I am also on Ubuntu.

Comment: my javac version is 1.7.0_07, however, it works on my mac, whose javac version is 1.6.0_22.

Comment: I changed it back to 1.6.0_24 version, but it still fails when using ant generic to build the version 1800. Could you share some info on how you build this? Thanks.

Comment: Leoooo, try the version from Oracle. It's possible that your Ubuntu replacement doesn't work properly with `-source 1.5` option.

Comment: From ant generic cmd output, I saw the line with [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5. But on my mac, ant generic just works fine. Not sure what happens. Any help?

Comment: Jarekczek, could you elaborate a bit? Download the jdk pkg from Oracle? I did sudo apt-get install stuff before.

Comment: To use java provided by Sun/Oracle you need to install it in a different way. I guess it is a self-extracting script. So something like `sudo chmod a+x installer; sudo ./installer` should do. But I made a little mistake: I'm on Debian, not Ubuntu. Not a significant difference though. Anyway I suggest to use Oracle's jdk.

Comment: Hi Jarekczek, I am still confusing how to resolve this,,sorry...could you elaborate more? Currently, my mac has no problem doing ant generic, but my ubuntu has the problem of the compilation error....

Comment: Let's switch to [java chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java).

Comment: Sorry, I am not online just now. Would you mind do a gtalk then?

Comment: Leoooo, I think you should work with this on your own. Google for query "oracle java ubuntu" returns nice tutorials like [this one on wikihow.com](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the latest changes forgot to add a file to SVN. It happens. It is clear after commands:

```
svn blame src/org/homeunix/thecave/buddi/Const.java
svn log -r1800:1801
```

You could notify him about it. To build, use the previous revision, `1800`.

However I still have problems when `windows` target is executed. So I did

```
ant generic
java -jar build/Buddi-3.4.1.2.jar
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I did not see the file AccountBalance.java in the version 1801.I used Ubuntu to deploy it, and will try 1800.

Comment: I just tried to deploy the version 1800, but there is a compile error indicating:compile: